PowerPoint SlideZoom - Check on Shape
I like to check if there is a slide zoom object on a slide to set the property "Return to zoom" for all the "Slide zoom objects".
I saw this article - where they say, there should be a "HasSectionZoom" - but I don't find this on the shape object - therefore I cannot test if the behavior is in O365 different than in PPT2016.
Inserting a Slide Zoom in PowerPoint 2016 using vba
This help describes the "Slide zoom" - what I am looking for.
Question is, how to get shape objects which have a "Slide zoom" defined, how to set property "Return to Zoom" - how to get information which slide is the "Slide zoom" jumping to.

As Jamie mentioned in the thread you referred to (and still the case today in Office 365), there's a HasSectionZoom property in the object model, but it returns false, whether the shape has a section zoom (or any other zoom) applied or not.
It might be worth setting up a sample slide with the different zoom types applied and poking around the XML to see what's offered.

How to read the "HasSectionZoom"? Any idea? Is this property on the shape? I also don't find any help about it.

I can find the necessary information in the XML file - only question is, how to read this out efficiently. Any idea?

No idea, I'm afraid. I've done a little XML manipulation in VBA, but I'm not a C# guy.
